# Trying to check items in a checkboxlist if the values are stored in my DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, checkboxlist

I am trying to create code ( in c#) in my code behind file that will check items in a checkboxlist if the items are stored in a specific column in my database.  I am getting these values and storing them in an array.  I know the array is getting the correct values because i outputted each index to see it's contents.

Now, I am trying to loop through my array and check each item in my checkboxlist that is in my array.  I did an try / catch and it is saying

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can't figure out why I am getting this error.  Below is my code I appreciate any tips/help.

```
if (findRecordUser.LinuxDistros != null)
{
    string inputStr = findRecordUser.LinuxDistros;
    char[] delimiterChars = { ','};
    string[] distros = inputStr.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            CheckBoxListBrands.Items.FindByText(distros[i]).Selected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LabelName.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You indicated that your `CheckBoxListBrands` variable is a [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControlscheckboxlistv=vs.110%29.aspx) object.  Assuming you added each checkbox item using the same id you are now trying to use to find the checkbox in the list, you should use:

```
CheckBoxListBrands.FindControl(distros[i])
```

or possibly:

```
CheckBoxListBrands.Items.FindByValue(distros[i])
```

Comment: doing CheckBoxListBrands.FindControl(distros[i]) didn;t give me an exception.  Now how to I make it so it gets checked?

Comment: CheckBoxListBrands.FindControl(distros[i]).[Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) = True I think.

Comment: says checked isn't valid